# WPF Binding a control's zindex to a property doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

If I bind a control's ZIndex to a property, although the property is clearly called when I debug (the breakpoint is hit on the getter), the zindex doesn't seem to work (ie. the zindex doesn't change in the running application properly; the elements on the control are no longer clickable if I set the zindex to be bound to a property rather than a set value in XAML).
Any idea why, or how to fix this?  Thanks for the help!

```
        <views:LaunchableApplicationControl BorderThickness="0" 
            BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" x:Name="LaunchableApplicationControl"
            Grid.Column="1" Margin="25,150,25,50"  
            Panel.ZIndex="{Binding LaunchableControlZIndex}" 
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            DataContext="{Binding LaunchableApplication, Mode=OneWay, 
            Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
```

Comment: Apparently that control is child of a Grid and put into column 1, rows 0-1. If there aren't any other controls in the same grid cells, setting ZIndex has no effect, because it's relative to the other children of the direct parent, i.e. the Grid.

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with that.  The zIndex DOES have an effect, but binding it dynamically to a property just has no effect.  If I call Canvas.SetZindex() on the control, that does work.

Comment: Property of the main view.  It does get hit - if I set a breakpoint, it stops in the get of the property on startup, but the zIndex fuctionally performs like it's -1 - nothing is interactable on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=LaunchableApplicationControl}"` and bind to a property which will set `ZIndex`. Make sure you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` `interface`.

```
        private int _Zindex;
        public int Zindex
        {
            get { return _Zindex; }
            set
            {
                if (_Zindex == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _Zindex = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Zindex");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I did, and it DOES bind.  The zIndex gets set.  BUT the effect it has is wrong.  The elements on that control are no longer clickable, as though they've had their zIndex set to -1.  
Setting it via Canvas.GetZIndex((UserControl)this.FindName("LaunchableApplicationControl")); absolutely does work, and has the desired effect.  I have no idea why that would behave differently than binding to a property.